# How to use @DbEnumValue with Ebean in Kotlin?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, annotations, kotlin, ebean

## Background

I'm trying to convert this Ebean example from Java into Kotlin:
http://ebean-orm.github.io/docs/mapping/extension/dbenumvalue

Here's the sample Java code:

```
public enum Status {

  NEW("N"),
  ACTIVE("A"),
  INACTIVE("I");

  String dbValue;
  Status(String dbValue) {
    this.dbValue = dbValue;
  }

  // annotate a method that returns the value
  // in the DB that the enum element maps to

  @DbEnumValue
  public String getValue() {
    return dbValue;
  }
}
```

## Kotlin

I expected the following in Kotlin:

```
// ERROR: This annotation is not available to target 'value parameter'
enum class Status(@DbEnumValue(storage = DbEnumType.VARCHAR) value: String) {
    NEW("N"),
    ACTIVE("A"),
    INACTIVE("I")
}
```

Or maybe:

```
// ERROR: Expecting , or ) after "value:String"
enum class Status(val value:String
                      @DbEnumValue(storage = DbEnumType.VARCHAR)
                      get() = value) {
    NEW("N"),
    ACTIVE("A"),
    INACTIVE("I")
}
```

The following makes sense to me and actually compiles, but the combination of the `dbValue` parameter for the constructor with a separate `value` field with getter for the annotation feels wasteful somehow.

```
enum class Status (val dbValue:String) {
    NEW("N"),
    ACTIVE("A"),
    INACTIVE("I");

    val value: String
        @DbEnumValue(storage = DbEnumType.VARCHAR)
        get() = dbValue
}
```

When I let IntelliJ convert the Java to Kotlin, it does this:

```
enum class Status private constructor(dbValue: String) {
    NEW("N"),
    ACTIVE("A"),
    INACTIVE("I");

   var value: String internal set

    init {
        @DbEnumValue(storage = DbEnumType.VARCHAR)
        this.value = dbValue
    }
}
```

I added the annotation to what IntelliJ produced, but it took me several guesses to figure out where to put it.

## Questions

- Why `private constructor`?
- Why `var value` without a get()?
- What is `internal set`?
- Why `init`?
- Why the extra `dbValue` variable? (I think to pass the value from the constructor to the public annotated get method).
- Is that even right?
- What is the idiomatic way to do this?

Any explanation, correction, or improvement would be appreciated.  If you think this belongs on codeReview, I'm OK with you moving it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the cleanest solution is to use `@EnumValue` instead of @DbEnumValue:

```
enum class Status {
    @EnumValue("N") NEW,
    @EnumValue("A") ACTIVE,
    @EnumValue("I") INACTIVE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the second way is the  cleanlst, just a bit of syntax error

```
enum class Status(@get:DbEnumValue val value: String) {
    NEW("N"),
    ACTIVE("A"),
    INACTIVE("I")
}
```

kotlin docs link:[Annotation Use-site Targets](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets)

Comment: You should add some explanation. Just pasting code is not a good way to help other people.

Comment: Aah, you added `get:` - makes sense.  I'll have to try it.

Comment: @akuzminykh ok,I well change it